# How to use the key event of Android emulator keyboard?

Tags: android, textview, keyevent

I make simple maths app (Calculater).Like Addition Subtraction etc.
So I take three Editview two for question and one for Answer. I use the `longKeyPressed` event and get the Result when user press the enter key of Android emulator. For this I use the keycode of entet key and apply in the longKeyPressesd method but no solution.
My code is

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyLongPress(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
{
    switch (keyCode) 
    {
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER:
        if(!(txtAnswer.getText().toString().equals(" ")))
        {
            checkAnswer(Integer.parseInt(txtAnswer.getText().toString()),correctOption);
        }else
        {
            genHelper.showToast("Another evenet ::->"+event.getKeyCode());          

        }
        break;

    default:
        genHelper.showToast("Default key Pressed:->>->"+event.getKeyCode());
        break;
    }
    return super.onKeyLongPress(keyCode, event);
}
```

genHelper is my Genral class for use reuseability purpose.

Now Today I use `OnEditorActionListener` for find the result but the keycode emulator kaypad

My New Code is below

```
txtOnes.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() 
                {   
                    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) 
                    {

                        if (event != null&& (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) 
                         {
                             genHelper.showToast("Key Code-->"+event.getKeyCode());
                             genHelper.showToast("System Key Code-->"+KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER);
                             if(txtTens.getText().toString().equals(""))
                                {               
                                    forTens=0;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    forTens=Integer.parseInt(txtTens.getText().toString());
                                }                           
                                forOnes=Integer.parseInt(txtOnes.getText().toString());
                                forOnes=forOnes+forTens;
                                txtAnswer.setText(String.valueOf(forOnes));

                             return true;
                         }else
                         {
                             genHelper.showErrorLog("Else part here ones");
                         }
                        return false;
                    }
                });
```